# SSL certificate warning on some browsers

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have a site running with an SSL certificate from Comodo/InstantSSL which should have 99% compatibility.

In my testing everything seems to work fine, however I've had some users send me screenshots of browser warnings about the security of my site:

[image: Android warning]
[image: IE warning]

Security warnings have been seen on IE 11 and Chrome 52 so the certificate should be valid.

The site is https://sololet.com

Can anyone tell me how I can debug this situation and find the problem, as like I said, it works fine for me on iPhone, iPad, Safari on MAC.

Thanks

Comment: Open in incognito mode and use authorized certificates.

Comment: what version of chrome do you use?

Comment: The person that reported the problem was using 52.0.2743.85 and i'm using 51.0.2704.103

Comment: Works fine for me in incognito mode.

Comment: `COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA` needs to be transmitted aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had such an issue with mobile clients (also a commodo certificate).

For (at least) Android clients you need to use a full-chain-certificate that includes your root- and intermediate certificate besides your domain certificate. This is also the result of a ssl-sitecheck at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?viaform=on&d=sololet.com

You should have received both files from commodo or your respective reseller.

Combine all 3 files into one and use that file as certificate in your vhost configuration. 
Combine like:
YOUR-CERT

ROOT-CERT

INTERMEDIATE-CERT

That solved our issue.

Comment: You're right: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?viaform=on&d=sololet.com reports "This server's certificate chain is incomplete".

Comment: Thanks for that link Tom.

Comment: Jojo, I currently use nginx and provide the config a `.crt` and `.key` file. Are you saying I need to combine them into the `.crt` file?

Comment: Ok, I think I have them added. I had tout `YOUR-CERT` first otherwise `nginx` wouldn't start. The saltiest site still gives the site an F but no longer says the chain is incomplete.

Comment: glad it worked for you. Thanks @Tom for the link, I updated the answer with it as it provides good extra information

Comment: Just read back my comment, typed too fast and missed half out. Anyway, what I was trying to say is that the order of the certificates has to have the `YOUR-CERT` first, then `INTERMEDIATE` then `ROOT` otherwise `nginx` won't start. All working now. Thank you.